# How to show the array data in textview with Tag and how to add more tag with search Functionality in user list in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm stuck when View Load first time i want to show some array data with tag.And after this i want to add another tag like more than one.

I'm using Third party: TITokenField

```
  NSArray * names=ary_ContactDetail;
    TIToken * token=[_tokenFieldView.tokenField addTokenWithTitle:[names objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % names.count)]];
    [token setAccessoryType:TITokenAccessoryTypeDisclosureIndicator];
    // If the size of the token might change, it's a good idea to layout again.
    [_tokenFieldView.tokenField layoutTokensAnimated:YES];
    NSUInteger tokenCount=_tokenFieldView.tokenField.tokens.count;
    [token setTintColor:((tokenCount % 3) == 0 ? [TIToken redTintColor] : ((tokenCount % 2) == 0 ? [TIToken greenTintColor] : [TIToken blueTintColor]))];
```

Please help me

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: I have added the Code

Comment: What tag contains , is it a number ? Do you want to increase tag number overtime user comes to this controller view or every time the app launches ?

Answer (score 0):

```
TIToken * token = [[TIToken alloc] initWithTitle:[self displayStringForRepresentedObject:representedObject] representedObject:representedObject];
[_tokenField addToken:token];
```

of use this method ..`- (TIToken *)addTokenWithTitle:(NSString *)title`

As I referred the library, this is the code for adding new token. I don't have working experience in this. And you have to manage the tag array also.